# How can I insert into MySQL Using ReactJS without passing parameters to PHP page

Tags: mysql, sql, reactjs

I have my data are rendered with DOM using ReactJS, i can create dynamic object within the same page as:

```
return (
      React.createElement('form', {onSubmit: this.onSubmit, className: 'ContactForm', noValidate: true},
        React.createElement('input', {
          type: 'text',
          className: errors.name && 'ContactForm-error',
          placeholder: 'First Name (required)',
          value: this.props.value.name,
          onChange: this.onNameChange,
        }),


        React.createElement('input', {
          type: 'email',
          className: errors.email && 'ContactForm-error',
          placeholder: 'Email (required)',
          value: this.props.value.email,
          onChange: this.onEmailChange,
        }),
```

My query about how can I insert the data into DB like **SQLLight** without php in between

Comment: Where is your `sqlight` file located ?

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot.**

Both DBs you have mentioned are purely server side. Therefore you have to somehow pass data to the server and there using technology of your choice (php, nodejs, java, .net, ...) save it to the DB.

If you do want to have DB on client side (in browser) the closest thing you are going to get is wrapper like [pouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/api.html) or direct usage of underlying technologies like [indexed database](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), [web sql](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), maybe [web storage](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)